# Join on field with spaces

Tags: bash, join

Is it possible to join these two files on the second field?
I'm struggling to get anything out of join.

```
join -j2 -t "," file1.csv file2.csv
```

The above command gives me no output with no errors.

ommitting the -t "," sorta works but the fields are now jumbled although the sort is along the lines of what I want.

```
Academia" "http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1264990398.jpg","Lackadaisy  83,"Lackadaisy
Arithmophobia" "http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1238468042.jpg","Lackadaisy  12,"Lackadaisy
```

I'm simply struggling on getting the join to work based on the second column. I believe the spaces are screwing things up.

I imagine I could convert the space in the second field to an _ or remove the redundant 'Lackadaisy' but this seems a bit hackish.

edit: I removed 'Lackadaisy ' in the second field and reran

```
join -j2 -t "," file1.csv file2.csv
```

and still didn't get the desired output :(

file1.csv

```
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1264990398.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Academia" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1238468042.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Arithmophobia" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1292845744.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Backalley" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1257460213.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Balderdash" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1213771589.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Bedlamite" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1265228812.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Bee-line" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1313510695.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Begorra" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1168262128.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Benediction" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1190620435.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Blindside" 
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1213855098.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Blitzwagen"
```

file2.csv

```
83 ,"Lackadaisy Academia"
12 ,"Lackadaisy Arithmophobia"
100 ,"Lackadaisy Backalley"
78 ,"Lackadaisy Balderdash"
19 ,"Lackadaisy Bedlamite"
84 ,"Lackadaisy Bee-line"
108 ,"Lackadaisy Begorra"
24 ,"Lackadaisy Benediction"
41 ,"Lackadaisy Blindside"
18 ,"Lackadaisy Blitzwagen"
```

Using:GNU bash, version 4.3.0(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: desired output is: "http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1264990398.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Academia", 82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the spaces after the second field in `file1.csv` that seem to be causing the trouble. Given you are setting your field-separator to `,`, I am not aware of a way to get [join](/questions/tagged/join) to ignore these trailing spaces

One workaround involves passing `file1.csv` through [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to get rid of trailing spaces and feeding the output to [join](/questions/tagged/join) via [bash process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). The resultant command is pretty close to your original

```
join  -j2 -t "," <(sed 's/\s\+$//' file1.csv) file2.csv
"Lackadaisy Academia","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1264990398.jpg" ,83 
"Lackadaisy Arithmophobia","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1238468042.jpg" ,12 
"Lackadaisy Backalley","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1292845744.jpg" ,100 
"Lackadaisy Balderdash","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1257460213.jpg" ,78 
"Lackadaisy Bedlamite","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1213771589.jpg" ,19 
"Lackadaisy Bee-line","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1265228812.jpg" ,84 
"Lackadaisy Begorra","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1313510695.jpg" ,108 
"Lackadaisy Benediction","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1168262128.jpg" ,24 
"Lackadaisy Blindside","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1190620435.jpg" ,41 
"Lackadaisy Blitzwagen","http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1213855098.jpg" ,18
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `awk` (if you have trailing spaces, you can remove them by using the `sub` function of `awk`)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" ,"}NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{sub(/ *$/,"",$NF);$NF=$NF OFS a[$NF]}1' file2 file1
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1264990398.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Academia" ,83
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1238468042.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Arithmophobia" ,12
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1292845744.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Backalley" ,100
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1257460213.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Balderdash" ,78
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1213771589.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Bedlamite" ,19
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1265228812.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Bee-line" ,84
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1313510695.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Begorra" ,108
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1168262128.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Benediction" ,24
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1190620435.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Blindside" ,41
"http://www.lackadaisycats.com/comic/1213855098.jpg" ,"Lackadaisy Blitzwagen" ,18
```

- We load the second file in to memory creating an array that indexes the common column on both files and assigning the value of column 2.
- Once the second file is loaded, we move to the first file and modify the last column with the array value. We remove the trailing spaces using `sub` function.